# What can be used instead of the word 'depressed'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I heard that 'depressed' is used for serious conditions such as melancholiacs. Then what word could be used for daily lives?

Comment: Can you please be more explicit? I understand the first sentence, But I do not understand the question.

Comment: What about **gloomy**?

Comment: @TasneemZh: as I see it, **gloomy** is cause, **depression** is effect :( So they are not really interchangeable in all conditions

Comment: @H.Kim it would be helpful if you provided some context. Probably *sad*, but it really depends on the context.

Comment: @virolino Umm..Got it but it's hard for me to make examples to make it specific. 'I feel depressed on rainy days.' i dont even know if this sentence works, but what would you like to say in such situation?what word can be used instead of deperessed?

Comment: what about Glum ? (https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/glum) - Also Gloomy can be a feeling as well as a description of a light effect.

Comment: @virolino | "Gloomy" is an adjective that has the same meaning as "Depressed" but with less seriousness, since "Depression" is considered an illness. Moreover, the OP requested a synonym to **Depressed** not **Depression**.

Comment: You can use **pressed**, which is not the same as **depressed**.

Comment: What do you mean by *daily lives*? People who are depressed *do* experience it as part of their daily lives. I don't see how that rules out *depressed* as being a good word. There is a difference between *clinical* depression and descriptive depression.

Comment: @JasonBassford oh im so sorry. I just wanted to speak about minor, shallow depression but because of my poor english, I choosed the word 'daily-lives' as meaning of temporary(as an antonym of chronic). i'd better use temporary but it didnt pop up on my mind back then. and yup, chronic or not , depression is also a part of daily lives. I was silly.

Answer (score 3):

'Depressed' is used in a multitude of ways by English speakers, and its meaning may even be evolving at the present time. It is used in a strict technical sense, but also in a more casual and lazy way by speakers to mean anything between 'a minor case of the blues' to 'severe mental health challenges'.

As Virolino said, if you say:

> I feel depressed on rainy days.

Most people will immediately understand that you mean

> I often feel a bit sad on rainy days.

Technically, that person is not depressed at all (does not have clinical depression), and some would probably suggest that we should be phasing out this casual usage as it can both stereotype and belittle genuine sufferers. If society is trying to reduce the stigma associated with depression and mental illness, it does not help to have people suggesting it is the same thing as a minor case of the glums.

So, I would suggest you are right to try to find more accurate descriptions for cases of ephemeral sadness to cases of serious clinical depression.

> I feel a bit sad.
>
> I sometimes feel blue.
>
> He's not on top form.
>
> Her mood is affected by the weather.
>
> I feel really sad.
>
> They are suffering from (clinical) depression.

It may even be helpful to avoid the verb 'to be depressed' entirely (if talking of mental illness, and not 'I depressed the button with my finger'), because it is used so carelessly to mean many different things. 'Depression' is the illness, and is less likely to be underestimated or misinterpreted.

> I have depression.

Is clearly about someone with clinical depression.

> I am depressed.

Can mean just about anything on the scale of sadness.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel depressed on rainy days.

It is perfectly fine.

As I presented in a comment earlier, you can also use: **feel blue**, **feel down**, **apathetic**. If you use a dictionary (there are plenty on the net) you can find other synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: despondent, desolated, devastated

Comment: I think you mean *desolate* rather than *desolated*.